# php mail attachment displayed in mail body in encoded format

Tags: php, attachment

iam trying to send mail via php with attachments. the email body is ok but the attachment is displayed in the email body in some encoded format.  i have varied the code severally with no success.

this is the attachment as displayed in the email body

```
JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAy
IDAgUgovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFI+PgplbmRvYmoKNCAwIG9iago8PC9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVj
b2RlIC9MZW5ndGggO
```

the attachment code

```
// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/pdf name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--\n";
```

please assist, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) instead of writing your own code for sending attachments with your emails.